# Researching the frequency stability property

Tags: histogram, frequency

I have seen [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vVXbgbMp0oY) short, wonderful video about the frequency stability property (also there is another video from this guy under his Kickstarter project ArtOfTheProblem; they are both great, and I highly recommend them).

It basically said that when you have two sequences of 0s and 1s you can determine which of those two sequences was truly generated randomly (using a coin flip procedure) and which one was generated by a human trying to act randomly. The trick to discern the two sequences from one another starts with counting non-overlapping segments of length 3. For any sequence you pick, the proportion of times it occurs should be the same as all the other sequences.

Consider following example

```
1010001101
```

Three questions:

1st: Which 3 numbers should we observe? Or in another words, should the window of size 3 overlap? Is this the correct histogram?

```
2 x 101
1 x 010
1 x 100
1 x 000
1 x 001
1 x 011
1 x 110
```

Or if the window should not overlap then what to do with last 1:

```
1x 101
1x 000
1x 110
1??
```

2nd: Why should be observer 3 subsequent numbers? Does it have something to do that the string consist of two numbers (0 and 1)? What would happen if we observe 4,5,6 ... subsequent numbers?

3rd: Do you know some other channel on youtube like this one?

EDIT:
I've done experiments using (non)overlapping window, results are [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156040/statistical-hypothesis-testing-for-empirical-measurement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it that he means the sequences don't overlap. If you look at a sequence of length $n=3$, and the sequences are equally likely, then the probability of any sequence is $\frac{1}{2^3}=\frac{1}{2^n}$, since there are $2^3=2^n$ possible sequences.

Now say you observe length $n$ sequences $m=10$ times. Then that's a total of $n\cdot m = 30$ numbers. But instead of thinking about $30$ numbers, think about $10=m$ indicator functions that are based on the $10$ sequences of three you saw. Define $1_1, \ldots 1_m$ as indicator functions that are just $1$ if your sequence that you pick is observed, and $0$ otherwise. The sum of these indicators follows a binomial distribution with parameters $m$ and $p = 2^{-n}$. Let's call it $Y$.

So $Y = \sum_{i=1}^m 1_i$. By the law of large numbers $\bar{1} = \frac{Y}{m} \to \frac{m 2^{-3}}{m} = 2^{-3}$. This is true for any arbitrary sequence.

$\bar{1}$ is the proportion of occurences of any sequence you pick. If you looked at sequences of a difference length, replace $n$.

Comment: Given this analysis, could you now answer the questions?  Specifically, (1) should the algorithm look at overlapping windows or not (and why?) and (2)  what will happen when $3$ is increased (and, implicitly, why exactly might $3$ have been chosen for this test)?

Comment: Answering (1) objectively would (should?) involve knowing whether or not there exists a solution in the overlapping case. I don't know about that. I don't think the video is specific about this. As far as (2) goes, that's what my last paragraph answers. And I don't know why 3 was chosen for this test...perhaps because it was small, greater than 1, and not 2.

Comment: Taylor, thank you for reply bud i still did not get the point. My math background is not as strong as yours. I went lost when you start talking about summing indicators (just fancy name for saying if I've already saw the sequence?) and binomial distribution.

Comment: So to be more direct: don't look at overlapping sequences, and also make sure the total length is divisible by 3 so you don't have any leftovers/incomplete seqs of length 3. Question 2: there is no strong reason not to look at sequences of length 4,5,... etc. Questuon 3: no not really

Comment: 1. when there is very long sequence then the remainder wont have any significant impact on result or will it? The question might also stand: how long the input sequence must be so the possible remainder wont affect the result? Or what is the tolerable deviaton among histogram members? I thing there is not a clear answer for this and it is some deal in statistics or am I wrong?

Comment: 2. if the length of whole sequence will be n and window size will be chosen as n/2, n/3 or even n/4 then I suppose it wont tell much about data? So why n/100 is OK but n/2 is not - how can one find this magic number? I still did not get why the winodow should not overlap, I suppose it is again depending on input length.

Comment: I am going to post some experimental results on larger input, with (non)overlapping window of various size (and step) on human generated vs random generated input. Should I start new question for this or update this one?